# Axis is specified but .drop() errors out

Tags: python-3.x

I've a data set with 3 columns:

```
    UserID          ProductID   Ratings
0   AKM1MP6P0OYPR   0132793040  5.0
1   A2CX7LUOHB2NDG  0321732944  5.0
2   A2NWSAGRHCP8N5  0439886341  1.0
3   A2WNBOD3WNDNKT  0439886341  3.0
4   A1GI0U4ZRJA8WN  0439886341  1.0
```

I'm trying to drop the rows where the UserID count is les than 50, that is if the user has rated less than 50 products. So I ran the code below:

```
for i in data.UserID.unique():
    print (i)
    if(data['UserID'].loc[data['UserID'] == i].value_counts().values < 50):
        data.drop(data.loc[data['UserID'] == i], axis = 0, inplace = True)
```

But I receive an error message stating the labels are not contained in an axis like so:

> KeyError: "labels ['UserID' 'ProductID' 'Ratings'] not contained in axis"

Could anyone please tell me what I'm getting wrong?

Thanks!